# PHP phalcon 1.2.6 accesing Relation object

Tags: php, model, phalcon

```
public function initialize(){

    $this->hasMany(
        "id",
        "\admin\m\RoutesStopsTimes", 
        "routes_stops_id",
        array(
            'alias' => 'RoutesStopsTimes'
        )
        );

   }
```

I have this in relations for RoutesStops, and

```
    $this->belongsTo(
    "routes_stops_id",
    "\admin\m\RoutesStops",
    "id",
        array(
            'alias' => 'RoutesStops'
        )
    );
```

When i access RoutesStops object without method toArray() it  shows:

```
[admin\m\routesstops$\admin\m\routesstopstimes] => Array
 (
[0] => Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Relation Object
     (
        [_referencedModel:protected] => \admin\m\RoutesStopsTimes
        [_referencedFields:protected] => routes_stops_id
      )
 )
```

I didnt copy all the information, bet here you can see that somehow it works, but i cant acces RoutesStopsTimes model data with RoutesStops model..

And somehow figured it out, that it works on findFirst only!

Comment: If you wanted it to work with find(), you'd have to iterate over the full result set and get the related model for each record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

findFirst and find returns different objects with different methods.

if you get set of results, you have to iterate:

```
$rows = \admin\m\RoutesStopsTimes::find();

foreach($rows as $row){
    var_dump($row->RoutesStopsTimes)
}
```

and

```
$row = \admin\m\RoutesStopsTimes::findFirst();
var_dump($row->RoutesStopsTimes);
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, figured it out by myself, but also was the answer! :)